# Module has no exported member when pushing to Github

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx

I'm using NX workspace with TypeScript, and I have an imported module which causes no errors whatsoever in run time, and no errors are shown in vs-code - because the module is imported correctly. However when trying to push to Github and building the project, it strangely throws that error

When I move this member into another file in that lib and import from there, it does work. Is there any kind of restart that needs to be done in order to fix this error?